# How to remove characters from column string?

Tags: r, substring

I had a database with the following column names (each one correspond to an observation of an individual in different years, i.e. year 1, year 2):

```
Session <- c("Evidims_01_001_1", "Evidims_01_001_2", "Evidims_01_001_3", "Evidims_01_002_1", "Evidims_01_002_2", "Evidims_01_003_1", "Evidims_01_003_2" "Evidims_01_003_3", "Evidims_01_003_4", "Evidims_01_004_1")
```

My idea is to create a wide table, but first I want to delete the strings: "Evidims_0x_00x_y" and just keep the last number in each of the names, ie "1", "2".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
sub('.*_', '', Session)
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "1" "2" "1" "2" "3" "4" "1"
```

Comment: you save me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could help too:

```
regmatches(Session, regexpr("\\d+$", Session, perl = TRUE))

[1] "1" "2" "3" "1" "2" "1" "2" "3" "4" "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
sub(".*(\\d+)$", "\\1", Session)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(Session, whitespace = '.*_')
[1] "1" "2" "3" "1" "2" "1" "2" "3" "4" "1"
```